# Can a roof A/C be installed on a concrete slab on the floor without being on a mounting?

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air

An A/C company came out and replaced my A/C with a new unit a few years ago. I've had A LOT of problems with it freezing since then. I noticed a lot of mold on the bottom of the unit itself and it seems as if it is not draining properly, there is constantly a huge puddle of water- so much so that it has actually made a hole in the driveway. (The ducks come and hang out by it because of the water!)

I called the company and they're telling me it's all fine, that the mold is because the duct work is leaking cold air- but the duct work is behind the are where the mold is. Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the unit 7 years old?  If you have duct leaks,could see why a lot of water.and mold.  Also the trap to drain water is not wright. Letting in air not helping.

Comment: So is this an "all in one" unit that I'm use to seeing split into an outdoor compressor and an indoor air handler?  What part of the world are you in?

Comment: @JPhi1618 it's regional and it may be builder preference. In my semi-arid US climate, many of the homes around me are built with a crawlspace and all the ducts are run under the home. It's normal to see a package RTU at the side of a house. My last one was sitting flat like the OP's unit. My new one is sitting on its shipping rails to keep it off the pad.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1):

A roof unit usually has more air flow around them so they dry out easier. The moisture is Norman and part of how air conditioners work, outdoor units are almost always drained on the ground. It is possible your unit needs to be washed down, dust builds up in the coils and turns into mud in the drip pan and can cause more issues but other than a good wash down your company is correct this is normal. If you decide to wash the coil and pan make sure to use low pressure water flow , I have replaced several outside units that home owners have destroyed using a pressure washer. No harsh chemicals if it needs chemical cleaning use a non acid cleaner, simple green is a good home owner option, I use a product made by my-Calvin called nu-bright, it is a non acid foaming coil cleaner that pushes the dirt out of the coils, after a treatment or 2 a clear water rinse has the system running better, also make sure to clean the drip pan it could be full of dirt, again clear water will work, I clean type unit every spring prior to the cooling season for best performance, as for water be happy you are making some, this says your coils are getting cold and taking the moisture out of the air. If your system was not making water it would not be cooling.

Answer (score 0):

Is that mold or is it moss/lichen? It's difficult to tell from the pictures, but that was my first impression because of the discoloration on the concrete pad. Either way, try washing the unit and see how long until it comes back. A power washer from a distance is safe as long as you're not aiming up at the coils. Or a garden hose and scrubbing. I wouldn't worry about it unless you're seeing mold where it counts--on the coils inside the unit. A trained HVAC professional can easily check this for you.

As Ed Beal posted, the moisture is indeed normal. Mine has been dripping all day (onto the ground). My installer didn't put any piping in place though. I don't know if that's bad or not. :(